# jQuery.post return -1 on one PC but success on the other PC

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I am doing some jquery ajax coding using jQuery.post.   On my PC ( the pc I use to edit code through ftp ) the code works perfectly ( I already put the code live on external host/website ). But when I use my laptop or even my friends PC to check I always get -1 return.

This is the code I am using for .post

```
jQuery.post("<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>", data, function(response) {
                alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
            });

// admin_url is wordpress function to return ajax located file
```

It even happen at my office. On the PC i was editing the code. I get the correct return value. But not when I use the other PC.

So I want to ask that

1. Is there any way to debug this -1
2. What could be problem with this kind.

Comment: You could use firebug or another browser debugged to ensure the `POST` is sent correctly and the response is received

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I checked for that. I don't see anything morethan -1 in that too. ( if i check correctly )

Answer (score -1, accepted):

when you get (-1) are you logged in?

Comment: this should be a comment - its not an answer

Comment: oh !! ... i get -1 when i'm NOT logged in.  Does it matter ? How I can solve it. Actually I am creating plugin for wordpress.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do.. if your plugin needs login privileges, then the user should be logged in to use it

Comment: exactly... seriously my bad..never thought of that. And actually i should add one more hooks  http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Viewer-Facing_Side . Thanks :)

Comment: You may want to turn this into an actual answer. In the meantime... -1